# Puppeteer horizontal scrolling not working

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, automated-tests, puppeteer

I am not able to scroll horizontally using puppeteer, neither left to right nor right to left.  Here is my code:

[horizontal scroll code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4DHW.png)

[view of scroller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYjaJ.png)

Comment: Hi Atul, welcome to SO! Please paste your code into your question rather than a screenshot, it would be much easier to test.

Comment: await page.evaluate( ()=> document.querySelector('#root > div > div.App-centeredContainer > div.MultiForm.MultiForm-progressPosition-top > div.MultiForm-pageHolder > div > div > div > div > div > div > div.Row.Row-align-left.Row-align-top.Row-wrap > div > div > div.FormComponent-contentContainer > div.FormComponent-content > div > div > div.input-range > div > span:nth-child(3) > div').click);
      await page.evaluate(()=> window.scrollBy(0,900));

Comment: Ok, to be more specific: There's a screenshot in your post with some HTML. Please press the **edit** button under your post and replace the screenshot with the actual HTML, so it can easily be copied and tested. The additional code you've supplied in your comment might also be helpful, but it's too difficult to read in a comment. Please format it and add it to your post. The easier it is to read and test your problem, the more responses you're likely to get!